# INDEX with dynamic File Path String

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am creating a sheet and I want to have dynamic file path references.

Each month the File path changes predictably, so I created a drop down menu to change Periods that the user will update before running a new month's reports.

I have successfully typed a path in directly to an index function as so:

`=INDEX('J:\Retail Finance\Varicent\Reporting\FY16\P08 Reports\[Feb Award File.xls]TS Summ'!$G$17,1,1)`

that provides the value in the referenced Excel file in G17.

However, this file would be so much more useful If I could reference a cell that contains a formula for the current month's report file path.

On the sheet I have in cell H6 the following:
       =`"'J:\Retail Finance\Varicent\Reporting\FY"&B$14&"\"&B$15&" Reports\[" &B$17 &" Award File.xls]TS Summ'!" &J1`

H6 evaluates as:[image]

Then I have an Indirect formula as follows:

```
=INDEX(H6,1,1)
```

But that returns just the text of the file path and not the contents at that location.

How can I change my syntax to get the contents of the referenced cell?

Thanks in advance. This would be a huge breakthrough for me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the **INDIRECT**() function.

For example, if A1 contains the text: [test1.xlsx]Sheet1!$A$1
(this could be a formula that evaluates to whatever you need for the reference to the file, sheet, and cell)

Then use this to get the value:

> =INDIRECT(A1)

INDIRECT() Does not work with closed workbooks, so you'll still have to open the external file. Because the file will be open, you can drop the whole Windows path part of your string.

Comment: Sure, but it refs out when I close the linked file.

Comment: I've not used the morefunc addin, but this includes INDIRECT.EXT() which should permit you to use the function with closed workbooks. Perhaps this will work for you: http://www.ashishmathur.com/extract-data-from-multiple-cells-of-closed-excel-files/